# Looping through tab separated file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a requirement in which I have to in which I have a " tab separated file" it has three columns.Sample six rows I have copied here

```
file_id        file_name   sample_id
30a6e42d      2f601196     TARGET-20-PABLDZ-04A
25fe4062      3ea58509     TARGET-20-PABLDZ-04A
839d38ec      5c971b6e     TARGET-20-PABLDZ-04A
79f40af8      4a2ace7c     TARGET-20-PADYIR-09A
afb79159      fea2f740     TARGET-20-PADYIR-09A
177500c8      1eae7be6     TARGET-20-PADYIR-09A
```

Each sample_id has corresponding 3 file_ids

My requirement is loop through all sample_id,and find all three file_ids

for each sample_id

cd `<file_id>`(the name of the folder is same as file_id). The `<file_id>` folder is in same location as where tab separate file exists.
get the file_name( The file exists in `<file_id>` folder)

cp  file_name to one directory

Thanks for your help

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `sed 1d input-file | while read file_id file_name sample_id; do .... ; done`

Comment: Not sure why you think you need to `cd` or why you need to get the filename given that you already know it.  Seems like the ellipses in my previous comment can simply be replaced with `cp "$file_id"/"$file_name" target-dir` and you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use awk's `system` function: CAUTION, this will create directories and attempt to move files.  Reader be warned: understand what this command does before you execute it. Perhaps insert 'echo' in various places to see the intended behavior.

```
awk 'NR>1{cmd=sprintf("mkdir -p %s; mv %s/%s %s", $3, $1, $2, $3 ); system (cmd) }' input-file
```

This assumes that you want to move the files to the directory named in the 3rd column (you don't indicate the name of your target directory, so I'm making a guess) and creates it before trying to move the file.

Comment: One small problem with this command that It is creating directories with ^M appended to those

Comment: @user3151878 The ^M is there because is exists in your input file.

Comment: @ William Pursell Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r column1 column2 column3 ; do
  printf "%b\n" "column1<${column1}>"
  printf "%b\n" "column2<${column2}>"
  printf "%b\n" "column3<${column3}>"
done < "myfile"
```

the  IFS=$'\t' is to tell bash that tab is the delimitter

Comment: From OP example, you wouldn't need to use IFS here.