# Move different files to new, individual directories based on list

Tags: linux, shell, awk, terminal, xargs

I have a directory containing >500 files styled like this:

```
GCA_000007345.1.fa.gz 
GCA_000681355.2.fa.gz
GCA_000802095.1.fa.gz
```

I also have a tab-delimited txt file *genomes_retrieved.txt* where in column 1 is the file name and column 2 is the name of the directory that should be made and where the file should be moved to.

```
GCA_000007345.1.fa.gz   Methanosarcina_acetivorans_C2A
GCA_000681355.2.fa.gz   Peptococcaceae_bacterium_SCADC1_2_3
GCA_000802095.1.fa.gz   Peptococcaceae_bacterium_BICA1-7
```

I tried to follow [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53457505/looping-through-tab-separated-file)  and use awk and xargs to execute in the directory where my files are. I create the directories

```
awk 'NR > 1{ print $2 }' ../genomes_retrieved.txt | xargs -I {}  mkdir {}
```

but I am not sure how to handle the mv part correctly.

```
awk 'NR > 1{ print $1 }' ../genomes_retrieved.txt | xargs -I {}  mv
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below trick to run a "scriplet" that uses positional arguments (`$1`, `$2`, ...) for the each-line words:

```shell
xargs -n2 sh -c 'mkdir -p "${2}" && mv "${1}" "${2}"' -- < genomes_retrieved.txt
```

Update: an easy way to see what you're actually running is replacing `sh -c` by `sh -xc`.

Note also that above CLI requires "sane" `files` and `directories` names (in source txt file), i.e. with no special characters like quotes (`'` , `"`), backtics, `$`, `(){}` and any other character that would be interpreted by the shell.

Comment: I get the same issue: *mv: cannot stat 'GCF_000183725.1.fa.gz': No such file or directory*. It is making the proper directories from column 2 but not moving the file there.

Comment: The files are expected to be there at the directory where you're running this, if you need to prefix a path you can modify it to run `mv "/path/to/files/${1}" "${2}"`

Comment: Thanks this worked well. I was running the command in the file directory but I was actually getting the error because of one name in ${2} that had an ' in it. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool, thanks for the feedback, will add note regarding file- and dir- names sanity.